# How to remove the "comments" bit that appears next to or below the posts

Tags: comments

I am modifying the Seven Five theme to fit my liking more and this is what I have.

What I want is to remove the "X comments" below the "Posted on" bit. However I just can't find which file to change. I have tried blog.php and index.php but none of them is the correct one. Any suggestions? I suppose it is a theme file and not a "core" wordpress one, am I wrong?

Comment: Its in a theme file and usually single.php or page.php

Comment: there is a limited amount of template files in the theme - have you searched them all?

Answer (score 1):

Does your theme have a comments.php, or a loop.php? If you do look inside those files.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what you're looking at - sounds like you're looking at a post - if this is the case then the file you're after is single.php ( unless there is a bespoke template in the theme for displaying single posts ) .... if you're looking at categories then it would be category.php, pages then page.php etc - there can be any number of them in a theme so you'd have to nose it out yourself ..... what i do is go to a file eg single.php and add a bit of text something like echo"single"; to it and then browse to check if i've got the right template - if i see "single" written on the page then i know i'm editing the correct template ( these are template files in the theme directory wp-content/themes/yourtheme and nothing to do with the core [although you still might want to back them up before you adjust and if you update your theme in the futre you will overwrite your changes so you should note them])